# C# reflection types not matching even though hash codes are the same

Tags: c#, reflection

The code below sometimes lands in the catch case (added for troubleshooting). It occurs sporadically in production but we haven't been able to reproduce it in dev/test.

```
try
{
    attributeValue = lookupModelProperty.Property.GetValue(childModel);
}
catch (System.Reflection.TargetException ex)
{
    throw new Exception($"Site 4 modelAttribute.Property.Name: {modelAttribute.Property.Name} " +
            $"modelAttribute.Property.ReflectedType.AssemblyQualifiedName: {modelAttribute.Property.ReflectedType.AssemblyQualifiedName} " +
            $"modelAttribute.Property.ReflectedType.GetHashCode: {modelAttribute.Property.ReflectedType.GetHashCode()} " +
            $"childModel.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName: {childModel.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName} " +
            $"childModel.GetType().GetHashCode: {childModel.GetType().GetHashCode()} "
        , ex);
}
```

Here is an example of what gets logged (very lightly censored)

```
Error: System.Exception: Site 4 
modelAttribute.Property.Name: XXXPropertyName 
modelAttribute.Property.ReflectedType.AssemblyQualifiedName: XXXClassName, DynamicAssembly_XXXAssemblyNamespace, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null 
modelAttribute.Property.ReflectedType.GetHashCode: 39642089
childModel.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName: XXXClassName, DynamicAssembly_XXXAssemblyNamespace, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null 
childModel.GetType().GetHashCode: 39642089  

---> System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
```

We expected the code to always work and return a value but sometimes the reflection access fails and the PropertyInfo ("ReflectedType") and childModel types seem to be the same based on the logging.

Comment: Try outputting the MetadataToken property of the two types.

Comment: Possibly Entity Framework mocking classes are involved?

Comment: I'll try the MetadataToken but it'll be a while before the next release unfortunately. No EF mocking involved.

Comment: The MetadataToken values are different! I don't understand how that is the case but the code was getting the metadata twice and I guess the way it is generated means we get different token values each time. I have a change to reuse the metadata instead of getting it twice that I have more confidence will fix the issue now. I'd like to dig into what the MetadataToken is and why it differs but there's never enough time to learn everything. That said if someone has a link or links to an explainer I can put them on my "read when I have time" list.